# Comparing two Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

I asked a similar question earlier in the week but I don't think my original description of the problem was very coherent, so I am trying again.

I have the following Dictionaries:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>> 1stDict = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, double>> 2ndDict= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>();
```

I need to create a third Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, double>> 3rdDict= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>();
```

Containing Dictionaries with  values from 2ndDict where DateTime does not exist in 1stDict.

I've made some attempts using nested foreach statements but having no luck.

Any advice?

Thanks, Brian.

Comment: Are you using the dictionarys keys as indexers into this dictionary, or do you just store the key and value together to have a pair of data points? If so, you want to look at a Tuple, might make this easier to understand.

Comment: How do you deal with the non-unique nature of the DateTimes?  IOW - if 2nd contains ["ab", ['12/26/2000', 7.43]] and [cd, ['12/26/2000', 9.92]] and 1st does not contain ['12/26/2000'] anywhere, which of the pairs from 2nd do you pick?

Comment: Hmmmm, funny object model, any chance you can convert those dictionaries into real objects with meaningful names?

Comment: Maybe you should try to explain what you're doing, the conversions you're doing are probably not the ideal way of doing this.

Comment: Ok I'll try to elaborate. I'm using this to update the value of some securities. 1stDict contains a dictionary of securities and the DateTime of each update for each security:
security1    security2
DateTime   DateTime
DateTime   DateTime
DateTime   DateTime

2ndDict contains a dictionary of <DateTime,Price> for each security 
security1          Security2
<DateTime,Price>   <DateTime,Price>
<DateTime,Price>   <DateTime,Price>

Comment: @Brian: That's even more confusing, I think you should take some time reading posts on SO about linq and collections and maybe you'll see some structures that make more sense..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var thirdDict = secondDict.ToDictionary(
    x => x.Key, 
    x => x.Value.Keys.Except(firstDict[x.Key]).ToDictionary(y => y, y => x.Value[y]));
```

Comment: Took me a minute to figure out how this was working, but this is right. Good job figuring this one out..

Comment: While I agree that a whole different approach is better (as mentioned in comments under the question), this does answer the actual question that was asked. +1

Comment: In this example, would I put this within a foreach and iterate through each dictionary with it?

Comment: Jason, can you give an example of different approach?

Comment: Actually Jimmy I just tried this and it seems to work as it is except I am getting more results in each dictionary that I expected. I am looking for only 1 or 2 extra results but am getting anywhere from 40 to 80.

Comment: @Brian, can you give me some sample data?  Perhaps I misunderstood some aspect of your data structure.

Comment: This works perfectly, it was just me being daft at the time. Sorry, I should have come back sooner. Cheers.